# How to iterate over a Tuple using zipWith in Flux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I want to iterate over a base list that offers `referenceIds`. Then in the next step, I want to make multiple service calls and aggregate the results in a tuple.

Then as final step, I want to iterate over all my `referenceIds`, and return each generated `JSONObject` directly via the event stream.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<JSONObject> test(Integer pages) {
    pages = 1;
    return Flux.range(1, pages)
            .map(pageNumber -> Arrays.asList(1 * pageNumber, 2 * pageNumber, 3 * pageNumber)) //referenceIds for testing
            .flatMap(numbers -> Flux.fromIterable(numbers).zipWith(Mono.zip(a(numbers), b(numbers)))) //results based on reference ids
            .map(tuple -> {
                Integer number = tuple.getT1();
                Tuple2<List<String>, List<String>> lookup = tuple.getT2();

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("number", number);
                json.put("someMore", <fromLookup>);
                return json;
            });
}
```

For this example, the return types of methods `a()` and `b()` do not matter. The important part is:

If I just return `Flux.fromIterable(numbers);` everything works fine.
BUT when aggregating using `.zipWith()`, I'm only receiving the 1st element of the numbers list. All others are lost. Why?

Sidenote: I need to use `.zipWith()` to execute those method calls in parallel (some longer running transactions).

Comment: So my approach is probably wrong here? From having a `List<String> numbers`, I want to generate a `Tuple<List<String> number, Object anything>`, with anything being the results from further Flux/Mono calls. Maybe you could give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> All others are lost. Why?

From Flux class documentation:

> Zip this {@link Flux} with another {@link Publisher} source, that
>   is to say wait for both to emit one element and combine these
>   elements once into a {@link Tuple2}. The operator will continue
>   doing so until any of the sources completes.

You can do you a() and b() calls, zip the results, and then unwind `numbers` list to flux and add the result like this:

```
   .flatMap(numbers -> Mono.zip(a(numbers), b(numbers))
                .flatMapMany(tuple -> Flux.fromIterable(numbers).map(i -> Tuples.of(i,tuple))))
```

Comment: One more question: if I add this above, the tuple aggregation works in general. But the returned `Server Sent Events` that should be emitted by the endpoint start to emit when all data has been processed. I'd expect it to emit each `JSONObject` as soon as it has been created. But it does not? How can I change the final `map()` method to not wait for all data being aggregated?

Comment: That's what I expected, but it does not. The server sent events start wehn all data has been processed by the last map method. I would expect to see immediate events.

Comment: I will accept your answer and start a new question, as for the topic of this question on how to combine flux and zip is correct.